# Angular 12 :- Generate sequential numbers in Angular html components

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular and doing a todo list. I used Bootstrap accordion. So, everytime a new todo is obtained from Database, it will be shown in the accordion. The problem is, when I click on one Todo , all other todos are expanding. The reason is because they all have the same `id`. I tried to change it as shown in the code below, but that did not work. Is there any solution in general ?

Here is the **.component.html**

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample" *ngFor="let todo of todos_db; let i = index;">
  <div class="accordion-item" >
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne_{{i+1}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
         {{ todo.todo_title }}
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne_{{i+1}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        {{ todo.todo_description }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `id="..."` on a tag with `*ngFor`. This will generate many elements with the same ID. You can't do that. IDs must be unique. Why have an ID at all anyway?

Comment: @JeremyThille So, when the accordion link is clicked, the targetted Id is expanded. I am unable to find the syntax on how to generate non-unique id

Comment: But why do you need an ID at all? That's not how Angular works. Set `(click)="todo.expanded=!todo.expanded"` and then you can determine if each todo is expanded by looking at `<div expanded="todo.expanded">`, something like that. Generating IDs is absolutely not how Angular works.

Comment: @JeremyThille I switched from PHP to Angular, so I keep trying to relate both of them

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use some **Angular Bootstrap library** ([NgBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples), [MdBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/advanced/accordion/) etc.)

I made a [little demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9v482h?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion-basic.html) with NgBootstrap accordion.

Comment: I know about them, but I really wanted the syntax for the method that I used

Comment: @Skumar not all Bootstrap components works fine with Angular. Thats why we have alternative libs.